# "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=true" not working when application is loaded using Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, version, smo

I have an application that uses the SQL Management Objects (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll) and in order to make it work in .NET 4, I need to insert this block in the app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

It works, but if I execute this application from another application, using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myApplicationThatUsesSmo.exe")
```

It does not work. The LegacyV2Runtime is not activated.

I used this implementation:

http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/

to check if the LegacyV2Runtime is loaded, and it is not. If I run the application directly, or from within VS2010, the test passes and the Smo works.

Anyone knows what am I missing?

Comment: Well, very strange, there's certainly no good reason the app.config file wouldn't work when you use Process.Start().  It starts executables the same way as Windows does.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all bindings to try to get some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The file "myApplicationThatUsesSmo.exe.config" was indeed missing in the folder where "myApplicationThatUsesSmo.exe" was being started.

"myApplicationThatUsesSmo.exe" is set as a reference for "myApplicationThatCallsProcessStart.exe" and so it is copied to the "myApplicationThatCallsProcessStart.exe" output folder. But its config file is not. There was a build event coping this file, but some how it was erased and than things stoped working.

I will let this answer here, in case someone else face the same situation.